# Json parsing failed but absolute path works

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I try to parse a json from web in Form Load event in cycle.
But for unknown reason I get an Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.'

But when I check an unit by absolute path - it gives me value.

```
//var test = (string)ratesjson["Valute"]["AUD"]["CharCode"];
```

Please let me know where am I wrong.

```
private string url = "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js";   


private async Task<List<CurrencyRateMap>> GetCurrencyRates()
{
    var list = new List<CurrencyRateMap>();
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var ratesjson = JObject.Parse(result);

    //var test = (string)ratesjson["Valute"]["AUD"]["CharCode"];

    foreach (var x in ratesjson["Valute"])
    {

        CurrencyRateMap crm = new CurrencyRateMap {
            CurrencyCode = (string)x["CharCode"],
            CurrencyRate = (double)x["Value"]
        };
        list.Add(crm);
    }

    return list;
}


private async void MetroWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CurrentContext.CurrencyRates = await GetCurrencyRates();
}
```

Comment: cast `x` to `JProperty` then take its `Value` (property) then use this object instead `x` in your code or change `var x` to `var p` then add `var x = ((JProperty)p).Value;` ... bonus: use `decimal` instead `double` in other case IEEE 754 will kick you in the a...

Comment: There are no absolute paths in your code. `ratesjson["Valute"]["AUD"]["CharCode"]` is a chain of lookup calls. The fact it works means that `x` is a JProperty whose `Name` is a currency code eg `AUD` and `Value` is another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x` inside your loop is an object with property names such as `AUD` etc., the `CharCode` and `Value` properties are buried beneath that level. However, it would be much easier to parse your JSON into actual C# objects. They are far easier to write code against and much safer. For example:

```
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, CurrencyRateMap> Valute { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyRateMap
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string NumCode { get; set; }
    public string CharCode { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var ratesjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(result);

list = ratesjson.Valute.Select(v => v.Value).ToList();
```